# Implict conversion from both string and int from same class?

Tags: c++11, c++14

How can I have implicit conversion operators to both string and int?

Simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Value
{
    operator std::string() const { return "abc"; }
    operator int() const { return 42; }
};

int main() {
    Value v;

    std::string s;
    s = v;  // error here

    // lines below not really needed
    int i;
    i = v;

    std::cout << s << " " << i << "\n";
}
```

c++11 compiler or later. These are the errors, reported on the string assignment line.

```
sandbox/casting_main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sandbox/casting_main.cpp:14:7: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ and ‘Value’)
     s = v;  // error here
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from sandbox/casting_main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:550:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       operator=(const basic_string& __str)
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from sandbox/casting_main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:569:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       operator=(_CharT __c)
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from sandbox/casting_main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:587:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       operator=(basic_string&& __str)
       ^
```

Apparently in the c++11 standard, there is a basic_string assignment operator:

```
basic_string& operator=(charT c);
```

This assignment operator causes an ambiguity that the compiler cannot resolve.

Is there any way to have implicit conversion operators to both string and int in the same class?

Comment: You already have both of those operators in the class. The problem is with `s = v;` , not with the class. One possible fix would be `std::string s(v);`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `basic_string` class, it defines(amongst other) following three overloads for assignment `operator=` :

```
// 1. Rvalue reference overload for basic_string
basic_string& operator=(basic_string&& __str);

// 2. Lvalue Reference overload for basic_string
basic_string& operator=(const basic_string& __str);

// 3. Overload for type value_type (set as char, see std::string typedef below)
basic_string& operator=(value_type __c);
```

The `value_type` is defined as following:

```
template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_string
    : private __basic_string_common<true>
{
public:
    typedef _CharT                                       value_type;
```

And the `std::string` is defined as:

```
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > string;
```

As you can see, `_CharT` is set to be `char` in the above typedef. Now the line that gives you error is:

> ```
>    s = v;  // error here
> ```

**The problem is that for the above assignment, all three `basic_string` type operator overloads are a match.**

The `1.` and `2.` overloads match because you have defined implicit conversion from `Value` to `std::string` type. The `3.` overload matches because of implicit conversion from `int` to `char` and the `Value` type has implicit conversion to `int`.

And it is because of this ambiguity the assignment is in error. I guess the only way around it is to remove one of the implicit conversion from your `Value` class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty, but can be done with SFINAE. We create a template conversion operator but constrain to to only convert to int or std::string, then use `if constexpr` to perform the correct behavior.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Value
{
    template <typename type, typename = std::enable_if_t <std::is_same_v <type, std::string> || std::is_same_v <type, int>>>
    operator type () const {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v <int, type>)
            return 42;
        else
            return "abc";
    }
};

int main() {
    Value v;

    std::string s;
    s = v;  // error here


    // lines below not really needed
    int i;
    i = v;

    std::cout << s << " " << i << "\n";
}
```